# Javascript hide table row on combo selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is what I try to do, when page loads up, i have 2 selections:
Deal Memo and Amendment. and 2 text box to input date: start date and end date.

now, i want to hide start date if user selects Amendment from the combo selection.

any idea?

[ sorry, here to post my code ]

```
<select name="formType" id="HiringType" >
<option value='Deal Memo'>Deal Memo</option>
<option value='Amendment'>Amendment</option>
</select>

<tr><td>Start Date: </td><td colspan=4><input type=""text"" name=s_date id=""startPicker"" size=20></td></tr>
<tr><td>End Date: </td><td colspan=4><input type=""text"" name=e_date id=""endPicker"" size=20></td></tr>
```

so I want to hide Start Date row (entire row) when user selects Amendment.

Comment: `$("#selectID").change(function() { if (this.value == X) { date.hide(); } });` off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv8GV/6/)

```
<select id="selectList">
    <option value="-1">select</option>
    <option value="1">Amendment</option>
    <option value="2">Deal Memo</option>
</select>
<br/>
<span class="startDate">startdate</span><input type="text" class="startDate"><br/>
<span class="endDate">  enddate  </span><input type="text" id="endDate">

$("#selectList").change(function(){
    var selected = $("#selectList").val();
    if (selected == '1') { $(".startDate").hide(); }
    if (selected == '2') { $(".startDate").show(); }
    //etc ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: btw, what if i need to hide the start date first (when page loads up) and show it when something else is selected?

Comment: just copy this 2 lines of code from change function:                       var selected = $("#selectList").val();
    if (selected == '1') { $(".startDate").hide(); }                       and paste it outside. So when your page is loading it will take the selected value from selectList and compare that selection. If condition is satisfied startdate is hidden.